# NVD3 reuse values in multiple group charts

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

is there a way to tell NVD3/D3 to use the same X values for subsequent datasets that were used for the first dataset? Take a look at the example below.

```
var testdata = [
  {
    "key" : "Quantity" ,
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1141102800000 , 1271000.0] , ....
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price" ,
    "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 71.89] ,     [ 1138683600000 , 75.51] ,     [ 1141102800000 , 68.49] , [....
  }
```

Notice how the first coordinate (which I call x values) is repeated each time in the second dataset. If its using the same X value for each dataset, why not just reuse it? It just seems like such a waste. Especially with large amounts of data and many datasets/groups. Or perhaps there is something I don't see or understand. Any help would be appreciated.

Example data snippet taken from 
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/linePlusBarChart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the answer to your question is no. One of the main assumptions of D3 is that the data defines what is displayed. That is, the data are self-contained. If you want to reference other bits of data, this assumption is violated.

That said, you could have a data structure like this:

```
var testdata = {
  "time" : [ 1136005200000, 1138683600000, ... ],
  "values" : [{
    "key": "Quantity",
    "values": [ 1271000.0, 1271000.0, ... ]
  }, {
  ...
  }]
};
```

Then you would be able to define e.g. a line generator like this.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d,i) { return xScale(testdata.time[i]); })
             .y(function(d) { return yScale(d); });
```

You would use that like this.

```
d3.selectAll("path").data(testdata.values)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); });
```

That would save you the repeated definition of the x values. The disadvantage is that you need to explicitly index into `testdata.time`, which makes the code a bit harder to maintain and less easy to understand.